# MacOSX AppBundler Can't set Icon?

Tags: java, macos, bundle

I've bundled my Java `.jar` file to a MacOSX `.app` bundle using AppBundler. Everything works, however my icon isn't loading.

This is my `build.xml` file:

```
<project name="Rage Mage" basedir="." default="bundle-RageMage">
<taskdef name="bundleapp"
         classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
         classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-RageMage">
    <delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="appBundle"
        name="Rage Mage"
        displayname="Rage Mage"
        identifier="Rage Mage"
        icon="res/icon.icns"
        shortversion="Beta 1.1.1"
        mainclassname="ragemage.src.Window">
        <runtime dir="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home"/>
        <option value="-Xdock:icon=res/icon.icns"></option>
        <classpath file="dist/ragemage_beta1.1.1.jar" />
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

The `icon.icns` file is in my `.jar`'s `res` folder. No errors are thrown indicating that the icon hasn't loaded. I just get the standard Mac app icon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The icon shouldn't be inside your jar file. The `icon` attribute should be a path to the icon file on disk, typically relative to the location of build.xml, and it will be copied to the right place inside the generated bundle directory by the appbundler task. The `-Xdock:icon` option is unnecessary.

Comment: I placed it in the directory with the `build.xml` file, and I'm still just getting the default app icon.

Comment: @sparklyllama so you now have `icon.icns` next to build.xml, and the appbundler task has `icon="icon.icns"` to match? In that case I'd have expected it to work correctly.

Comment: That's exactly what I have.